# java-Passing argument into main method

Tags: java

i can't pass the name of files as argument to the main method. here is my code...

```
import java.io.*;

class four {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    int i;
    FileInputStream fin = null;

    try{
        fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found........");
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Index out of bound........");
    }

    do{
        i = fin.read();
        if(i != -1)
            System.out.println(i);
    }while(i!=-1);

    fin.close();
}
```

}

Comment: And what is the exception? What have you written at the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* pass them in; they just aren't doing what you think they are.

Echo out the command line arguments and you'll see your problem right away:

```
for (String arg : args) {
    System.out.println(arg);
}
```

I'm guessing that you either have unescaped Windows slashes ('\') or spaces in your file paths.

Escape the slashes and enclose each file path in double quotes and you'll have better luck.